# I want you to help me prepare a detailed customer statement report

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

The purpose of the report is to provide a detailed account of the customer showing the balance after each transaction between two dates and balance before the start date

I have a view from three tables in SQL Server. I want to extract the evidence from it on three basis dates beginning and end date. However, the previous balance is displayed on the client at the beginning of the report. How can this be done knowing that there is no balance column in the view .
I use stored procedures

[image]

I want the report outputs to be like this

[image]

I use this code but I have problem

```
declare @id_customer int 
;with initial as(
  select *
  from result
  where id_customer= @id_customer
),report as(
  select r.id,[balance]=isnull((select sum(b.debit-b.credit)
               from initial b
               where b.[date]<r.[date]) + r.debit - r.credit ,r.debit-r.credit)
  from initial r
)

 select [Operation type] = type,
        reference_no = r.id,
        [description],
        [Debit] = debit,
        [Credit] = credit,
        [Balance] = b.balance
 from result r
 inner join report b on b.id = r.id
 where r.id_customer = @id_customer
 order by r.[date]
```

some records come towc

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmkLH.jpg)

Comment: and for the moment what have you done? which are the errors you're getting?

Comment: I do not get errors but I want the report to calculate the balance after each process and in the past give me the balance before the beginning of the report and in the last balance on the client

Comment: Note that the Balance column does not exist in the view

Comment: While anyone can code for you and is possible someone do it asking for a "do my job for me" is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) note off-opic question attracts down votes

Comment: I updated my question I hope the be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, it's hard to guess without example data, but should work.
I assumed that transaction ID is incremental, so correct me if I'm wrong:

```
declare @id_customer int = 2
;with initial as(
  select *
  from result
  where id_customer= @id_customer
),report as(
  select r.id,[balance]=isnull((select sum(b.debit-b.credit)   
   from initial b   
   where b.[date]<=r.[date] and b.[id]<r.[id] ) +
   r.debit - r.credit ,r.debit-r.credit),r.date

  from initial r

)

 select [Operation type] = r.type,
        reference_no = r.id,
        [description] = r.description,
        [Debit] = r.debit,
        [Credit] = r.credit,
        [Balance] = b.balance,
        [Date] = r.date
 from result r
 inner join report b on b.id = r.id
 where r.id_customer = @id_customer
 group by r.id, r.type,r.debit,r.credit,r.date,r.description,b.balance
 order by r.[date]
```

Comment: run this query and post the results: "Select * FROM result where ID=3"

Comment: Repetition occurs when there is an invoice and receipt similar id number is repeated each one of them twice so I want a unique key to do the comparison process in the following code